# Pandas : filter the rows based on a column containing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to filter the rows in a data frame based on another column value?

I have a data frame which is,

```
ip_df:
     class    name     marks          min_marks  min_subjects
0    I        tom      [89,85,80,74]  80         2
1    II       sam      [65,72,43,40]  85         1
```

Based on the column values of "min_subject" and "min_marks", the row should be filtered.

- For index 0, the "min_subjects" is "2", at least 2 elements in "marks" column should be greater than 80 i.e., "min_marks" column then a new column named "flag" has to be added as 1
- For index 1, the "min_subjects" is "1", at least 1 element in "marks" column should be greater than 85 i.e., "min_marks" column then a new column named "flag" has to be added as 0 (i.e., flag=0 as the condition didnt satisfy here)

The final outcome should be,

```
op_df:
     class    name     marks          min_marks  min_subjects flag
0    I        tom      [89,85,80,74]  80         2            1
1    II       sam      [65,72,43,40]  85         1            0
```

Can anyone help me to achieve the same in the data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `zip` by 3 columns, compare each value in generator and `sum` for count, last compare by minimal marks and convert to integers:

```
df['flag'] = [1 if sum(x > c for x in a) >= b else 0 
                 for a, b, c in zip(df['marks'], df['min_subjects'], df['min_marks'])]
```

Alternative with convert boolean by `int` to `0,1`:

```
df['flag'] = [int(sum(x > c for x in a) >= b)
                 for a, b, c in zip(df['marks'], df['min_subjects'], df['min_marks'])]
```

Or solution with `numpy`:

```
df['flag'] = [int(np.sum(np.array(a) > c) >= b)
                  for a, b, c in zip(df['marks'], df['min_subjects'], df['min_marks'])]
```

---

```
print (df)
  class name             marks  min_marks  min_subjects  flag
0     I  tom  [89, 85, 80, 74]         80             2     1
1    II  sam  [65, 72, 43, 40]         85             1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `for` loop and make full use of parallel computations you can use the new function [`explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) (Pandas 0.25.0):

```
df1 = df.explode('marks')
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  class name marks  min_marks  min_subjects
0     I  tom    89         80             2
0     I  tom    85         80             2
0     I  tom    80         80             2
0     I  tom    74         80             2
1    II  sam    65         85             1
1    II  sam    72         85             1
1    II  sam    43         85             1
1    II  sam    40         85             1
```

Compare the columns `marks` and `min_marks`:

```
df['flag'] = df1['marks'].gt(df1['min_marks'])\
.groupby(df1.index).sum().ge(df['min_subjects']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  class name             marks  min_marks  min_subjects  flag
0     I  tom  [89, 85, 80, 74]         80             2     1
1    II  sam  [65, 72, 43, 40]         85             1     0
```